# Wordpress plugin install fail

Tags: wordpress

Today I am starting a new project and I am stuck on wordpress plugins installation

```
   Downloading install package from  
   https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/types.1.8.11.zip…

  Unpacking the package…

  Installing the plugin…

  The package could not be installed. No valid plugins were found.

Plugin install failed.`
```

I ve tried different plugins and all of them produce this error! any ideas?

Comment: You should try downloading a zip of the plugin. Then try installing by uploading the zip in the WP interface. This will help narrow down your problem.

Comment: is debugging enabled on your website? If so , does it give any errors on your website ?

Comment: @JamesJones, yes done that, also changed the permission, still the same

Comment: @Christophvh no its is not enabled, how to do it?

Comment: Does your server have sufficient disk space?

Comment: @AndrejsGubars add define( 'WP_DEBUG', true ); to wp_config.php

Comment: its all done locally, plenty of space

Comment: @JamesJones done, whats next?

Comment: Try downloading a plugin manually, unzipping and putting the files in a folder in `wp-content/plugins`. See if it can then be activated as normal

Answer (score 0):

you can use class-tgm-plugin-activation to install your plugin automatically at your theme 
 visit and download, https://github.com/TGMPA/TGM-Plugin-Activation 
include at your functions

Answer (score 0):

I managed to sucessfully install and activate it, right now. I used wp-cli, but that should not make much difference. I can recommend it though, as it is more verbose, which helps tracking down errors

What is the result of

```
ls -l .../path/to/wordpress/wp-content/plugins
```

Assuming you are on Linux/Unix. Do the other plugins have different permissions/users?

Comment: the result is `drwxr-xr-x@ 5 andrejs.gubars  staff  170  6 Jan 18:48 plugins`

Comment: This looks fine. What does it look like inside the plugins dir?

No writing for Webserver, unless it runs as your user, but that is fine.